# Too few arguments to function VMS\Http\Controllers\PenyediaController::store_paket(), 1 passed and exactly 2 expected

Tags: php, laravel, controller

> how to solve it?

```
public function store_paket(request $request, $id){
    if(!Session::get('login')){
        return redirect('/login')->with('alert','Kamu harus login dulu');
    }
    else{
        DB::table('tbl_paket')
        ->where('id_profil_penyedia', $id)
        ->get();    
        $data = new ModelPaket();
        $data->nama_pesanan         = $request->get('nama_pesanan');
        $data->id_kategori_produk   = $request->get('id_kategori_produk');
        $data->id_kategori_belanja  = $request->get('id_kategori_belanja');
        $data->id_pagu              = $request->get('id_pagu');
        $data->id_pembayaran        = $request->get('id_pembayaran');
        $data->save();

        Alert::success('Sukses!', 'Berhasil Menambahkan Paket Baru!');
        return redirect ('/tambah_paket');
    }
}
```

[image]

how do you enter the id_profil_penyedia into another table?
[image]
How do I call an id to be entered in another table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coba kayak gini slur

```
public function update_aduan(Request $request)
{

$alats =  $request->alat_id ;
$aduan = Aduan::findOrFail($request->id);

$aduan->id = $request->id ;

if ( empty($alats)) {

} else 
{
    $alat = Alat::find($request->alat_id);
    $alat->status_alat = $request->status_alat ;
    $alat->save();
}




$aduan->alat_id = $request->alat_id ;
$aduan->ipsrs_id = $request->ipsrs_id ;
$aduan->user_id = $request->user_id ;
$aduan->teknisi_id = $request->teknisi_id ;
$aduan->tindakan = $request->tindakan ;
$aduan->aduan = $request->aduan ;
$aduan->nama_pengadu = $request->nama_pengadu ;
$aduan->status = $request->status ;
$aduan->status_alat = $request->status_alat ;
$aduan->ended_at = $request->ended_at ;
$aduan->respon_at = $request->respon_at ;


$aduan->update();

return back()->with('success', 'Sukses Update Data');


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you add `$id` value to the routes on your forms ?
e.g. `route('name', $paket->id)`

Comment: Route::post('/store_paket/{id}', 'PenyediaController@store_paket');

Comment: like that?..........